# How can I do nested foreach loop in my blade?

Tags: laravel

I want to display the subjects in Laravel blade and related topics taught in each subject underneath the subject. how can I do that in Laravel 8.

This is my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class topic extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='topics';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable=['author_id', 'course_id', 'url', 'topic', 'powerpoint', 'description', 'views'];

public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo(author::class);
}

public function course(){
    return $this->belongsTo(course::class);
}
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function courses(){

    $topics = topic::join('authors', 'topics.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
    ->join('courses', 'topics.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
    ->select('topics.*', 'authors.first_name', 'authors.last_name', 'courses.course')
    ->get();

    $topicsCounter = topic::join('authors', 'topics.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
    ->join('courses', 'topics.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
    ->count();

    return view('courses', compact('topics', 'topicsCounter'));
}
```

This is my blade:

```
@foreach($topics as $topic)

    {{ $topic->course }} :
//here is where i want to list all the topic found in this specific course

    @endforeach
```

Is this a right way or i should be doing it in another better way?

Answer (score 0):

Use external component accept $course as parameter then include it inside your main blade.